# Understanding an assignment: Search for prime number above 1 quadrillion using servlets

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, servlets, primes

I am a student studying IT in an University. I've been giving an assignment of searching for prime numbers above one quadrillion. Steps have been given:

- Start number as one quadrillion
- Select odd-numbered candidates
- Divide them by every odd integer between 3 and their square root. if
  one of    the integers evenly divides the candidate, it's declared
  prime.

Now this is what i've come up with :

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class PrimeSearcher extends HttpServlet{
    private long number = 10000000000000001L;
private boolean found = false;
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    while(!checkForPrime(number)){
        number = number+2;
    }

    if(found){
        out.println("The first prime number above 1 quadrillion is : " + number);
    }

}

public boolean checkForPrime(long numberToCheck){
    double sqrRoof = Math.sqrt(numberToCheck);
    for(int i=3; i< sqrRoof; i++){
        if(numberToCheck%i==0){
         return false;
        }
    }
    found= true;
    return found;
}


}
```

My worry is that am not sure whether am on the right path and another issue is that this always one number ,the first one. after googling i found that on [servlet.com](http://www.javafaq.nu/java-example-code-1025.html) and [javafaq](http://www.javafaq.nu/java-example-code-1025.html) that they are using thread and i've run theirs and it seem to be cool. I don't really understand that one but it gives different numbers.

So I am now confused right now about how to implement that algorithm and i really don't want to copy that one. Maybe after understanding  their method i can code this algorithm better.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it looks OK, but you might need the `i` in `checkForPrime` to be a `long` type. And you're not incrementing `i` by 2 (you only need to check for odd divisors).

Just be prepared for this to take a long time.......

Answer (score 1):

Moreover you need to `checkForPrime` until `i<=sqrRoof` (sqrRoof could be an integer).

Answer (score 1):

you have 10 quadrillion written in your source code, not one quadrillion. Just so you know. :)

In case you need them, primes above one quadrillion are:

```
37,91,159,187,223 ...
```

Above 10 quadrillion:

```
61,69,79 ...
```

Comment: +1 .so you also agree that i should keep my code provided i added @EthanB suggestion?

Comment: both EthanB's and drakyoko's about the `<=`. and then, you're supposed to add multithreading to it, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to check a large prime is to generate a list of low primes, up to some limit, using the Sieve of Eratosthenes.  Use that list to check odd numbers in the quadrillion range, to eliminate most non-primes.

Then use the [Miller-Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin_test) probabilistic prime test to check if any remaining large number really is prime.  If you repeat the M-R test up to 64 times, then there is a far larger chance that your hardware has failed than that you have inadvertently found a composite number.

The M-R test is much faster than trial division for large numbers.

Comment: actually, near one quadrillion we only need about 2 million primes, which can be quite easily produced through Sieve of Eratosthenes in full, so there'll be no need in additional M-R testing. But it will take its time of course, to trial divide by all of them. -- ( sqrt (one quadrillion) = 3,163,000 ; 1,952,000 primes )

Comment: typo: sqrt (one quadrillion) = 31,623,000 ; 1,952,000 primes.